# GNU autotool:No rule to make target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu, automake, libtool

my first question in stack overflow!

**Quick overview** of my question: I use autotool to generate a C program. When I use *make* command, I meet the error:

```
No rule to make target `../lib_foo/libfoo.a', needed by `mistery_foo'.  Stop.
```

**Something detail** of my questions:

I am doing an assignment of my teacher, in which I should use GNU *autotool* to generate a very simple C program.

**File structure**: /project: main, lib_foo, Makefile.am, configure.ac

/project/main: main.c, main.h, Makefile.am

/project/lib_foo: foo.c, foo.h, Makefile.am

Following is what I write for configure.ac and makefile.am:

I. **"project/configure.ac"**:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.67])
AC_INIT([project1],[0.01],[cwentai01@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9 foreign])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([./lib_foo/foo.c])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_RANLIB
AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[#include <mistery.h>]],\
                [[ mistery_value(1);]])],\
                [AC_DEFINE([MISTERY_VALUE_ONEPARAM], [],[CONSTANT])],[])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([mistery_value],[magic vadoo mistery],[],[AC_MSG_ERROR([Libraries (mistery, magic, vadoo) not found])])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile  lib_foo/Makefile main/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

P.S. the AC_COMPLIE_IFELSE is used to judge the number of the parameters in function mistery_value(). I think it has nothing to do with the error.

II. **project/Makefile.am**:

```
SUBDIRS = main lib_foo
```

III. **project/main/Makefile.am**

```
LDADD = ../lib_foo/libfoo.a
mydir = ../uselessbin
my_PROGRAMS = mistery_foo
mistery_foo_SOURCES = main.c main.h
mistery_foo_LDADD = ../lib_foo/libfoo.a
```

IV. **project/lib_foo/Makefile.am**

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libfoo.a
libfoo_a_SOURCES = foo.c foo.h
```

Then I run with the order of commands:

```
>cd project
> aclocal
> autoheader
> automake -a
> autoconf
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ./uselessbin/mistery_foo
```

When I run *make* command, I got the error:

```
No rule to make target `../lib_foo/libfoo.a', needed by `mistery_foo'.  Stop.
```

I suppose the problem may be that I don't have *libfoo.a* properly installed. But the library *libfoo.a* should not be installed but only compiled so I have to use 'noinst_' in lib_foo/Makefile.am. That's why I get stucked here.

Any answers will be appreciated.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using recursive automake, and in this case, dependencies crossing directory paths will just not resolve to extra rules: `main/Makefile.am` does not know how to make targets in `lib_foo`.

The quick fix up is to change your `SUBDIRS` declaration in the top-level `Makefile.am` to:

```
SUBDIRS = lib_foo main
```

This way `main/mystery_foo` will only be built after `lib_foo` and its targets are built. Of course this does not allow you to just `make` in `main/` and have it work.

The other suggestion from the previous post, to use [non-recursive automake](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html) is a more proper solution, because then all the dependencies can be resolved from a single `Makefile.am`.

Answer (score -1):

Your procedure looks mostly totally fine. I just found a few possible *mistakes*:

1. Your configure.ac should have LT_INIT instruction
2. In project/main/Makefile.am I would change `../lib_foo/libfoo.a` to `libfoo.a`
3. If the previous doesn't work, I would recommend to have a single `Makefile.am` and not recursive `Makefile.am` (Recursive `Makefile.am` can be harder to code and might damage the performance of the compilation)

Comment: May I know why do I get down-voted, it's usually a custom to leave a feedback :)

Comment: Hey Vicente, I have solved this. The problem is that in project/src/Makefile.am, I set the subdirectory "main" before "lib_foo". So make will deal with "main" before "lib_foo". But the thing is  in src/main/main.c I need to use "libfoo.a", which is generated by src/lib_foo/foo.c. So I modify project/src/Makefile.am like "SUBDIRS = lib_foo main", and it works. Thanks for your help, by the way I don't know why there is a down vote here , it's not me:(