# How a c++ program (.cpp) work with header(.h) and libtool (.la)?

Tags: c++, linux, automake, libtool

I have create a folder in linux called helloworld. 
Inside this folder have sub-directory:

- include
- lib
- src

***include/***
In this directory I have create a header file called helloworld.h
content are:

```
class helloworld{
public:

       void getvalue();

};
```

***lib/***
In lib directory I have create a cpp file called helloworld.cpp
content are mainly functions:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<helloworld.h>
using namespace std;

void helloworld::getvalue() {

}
```

***src/***
In src directory I have create a main cpp file called main.cpp
content are main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<helloworld.h>

int main()
{
helloworld a;
a.getvalue();
}
```

but after I autoconf, automake, ./configure, and when make
it has a error:

`` helloworld/src/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `helloworld::getvalue()' ``

All I want is to use helloworld.cpp's functions in main.cpp. I've spend a lot of time searching and try and error. Please help.

Added the Makefiles.am

in parent directory,
 I have two files Makefile.am and configure.ac:

Makefile.am

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
SUBDIRS=src lib
```

configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([helloworld], [0.1], [helloworld@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_RANLIB
AC_LANG(C++)
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_DISABLE_STATIC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile lib/Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_SUBST([CC])
LT_INIT
AC_OUTPUT
```

In lib directory has one Makefile.am

```
INCDIR=../include
INCPATH=-I. -I$(INCDIR)
AM_CPPFLAGS=$(INCPATH)
lib_LTLIBRARIES=libhelloworld.la
libhelloworld_la_SOURCES=helloworld.cpp
```

In src directory has one Makefile.am

```
INCDIR=../include
INCPATH=-I. -I$(INCDIR)
AM_CPPFLAGS=$(INCPATH)
helloworld_LDADD=-L/lib/libhelloworld.la
bin_PROGRAMS=helloworld
helloworld_SOURCES=main.cpp
```

Compiled success if I take out the 
`a.getvalue();`

Comment: is `helloworld` a library or just another `.cpp` that you want to compile with `main.cpp`?

Comment: and if you have library is it dynamic or static one?

Comment: Since this is a question about autoconf/automake (not really about C++ by itself) maybe you should add your autoconf/automake scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using recursive make, you will need to add a special rule to `src/Makefile.am` to make sure the `lib/Makefile.am` rules for rebuilding the library are applied (untested here, but used in other projects).

This now means that a normal recursive build will build `.`, `include`, `lib`, `src`, and then `lib` again. I would strongly recommend ditching recursive make and use the one `Makefile.am` solution I have laid out in my other answer.

```
bin_PROGRAMS        = helloworld
helloworld_CPPFLAGS = $(top_srcdir)/include
helloworld_LDADD    = $(top_builddir)/lib/libhelloworld.la
helloworld_SOURCES  = main.cpp

$(top_builddir)/lib/libhelloworld.la:
        cd $(top_builddir)/lib && $(MAKE) libhelloworld.la
```

Answer (score 1):

```
helloworld_LDADD=-L/lib/libhelloworld.la


/lib/libhelloworld.la
```

this search lib from root directory not your project lib/ directory

Try

```
./lib/libhelloworld.la
```

or

```
../lib/libhelloworld.la
```

or

```
lib/libhelloworld.la
```

Comment: Not working too. I tried to moved all files together in on directory. Same issue.

Comment: @Jemttinhwa Nevermind. You added your makefiles. i changed my answer.

Comment: ../lib/libhelloworld.la => No rule to make target '../lib/libhelloworld.la' ......
lib/libhelloworld.la => No rule to make target 'lib/libhelloworld.la' ......
./lib/libhelloworld.la => No rule to make target 'lib/libhelloworld.la' <br> ......

Comment: @Jemttinhwa What is location of libhelloworld.la that your project generate it?

Comment: hmm.. its now in  /helloworld/lib/.libs/libhelloworld.la

Comment: I tried change to ../.lib/libhelloworld.la but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried these? ../lib/.libs/libhelloworld.la   ./lib/.libs/libhelloworld.la  lib/.libs/libhelloworld.la

Comment: Same error. *** No rule to make target '../lib/.libs/libhelloworld.la', needed by 'helloworld'.  Stop.

Comment: @Jemttinhwa  Can you change SUBDIRS=lib src like this. lib should come first. as this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785258/gnu-autotoolno-rule-to-make-target

Comment: You wellcome my friend. Finally we got it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good demonstration case for *not* using recursive make, because that simplifies the declaration of the executable depending on the library. Also, using a single `Makefile.am` helps with parallel builds (`make -j3`).

I have completed the example and put it up at [github.com/ndim/cxx-automake-lib-and-main](https://github.com/ndim/cxx-automake-lib-and-main) for your convenience.

The `configure.ac` now uses `LT_INIT` directly without deprecated macros, only generates one `Makefile`, and generates a `helloworld-config.h` config header to keep the compiler command line clean from all those `-D` defines:

```
AC_INIT([helloworld], [0.1], [bug-me-not], [helloworld], [this-url])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([lib/helloworld.cpp])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([helloworld-config.h])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([auto-m4])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([auto-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([
-Wall
-Werror
foreign
subdir-objects
])

AC_PROG_CXX
AM_PROG_AR
LT_INIT([disable-static])

AC_LANG([C++])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The top-level `Makefile.am` is now the only `Makefile.am`:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I auto-m4

EXTRA_DIST =
bin_PROGRAMS =
lib_LTLIBRARIES =

include include/Makefile-files
include lib/Makefile-files
include src/Makefile-files
```

Then `include/Makefile-files` deals with the header file which I put into `include/helloworld/helloworld` to help with keeping the include file namespace clean, and to prevent make from getting confused about the executable `helloworld` and the header file `helloworld`.

```
# -*- makefile-automake -*-
EXTRA_DIST += %reldir%/helloworld/helloworld
```

```
/* -*- c++ -*- */
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_HEADER
#define HELLOWORLD_HEADER

class helloworld {
public:
  void getvalue();
};

#endif /* !defined(HELLOWORLD_HEADER) */
```

Now, `lib/Makefile-files` will build `libhelloworld.la` from library source file `lib/helloworld.cpp` which I had to adapt a bit for the changed header name:

```
# -*- makefile-automake -*-

lib_LTLIBRARIES           += libhelloworld.la
libhelloworld_la_CPPFLAGS  = -I$(top_srcdir)/include
libhelloworld_la_SOURCES   = %reldir%/helloworld.cpp
```

```
#include "helloworld/helloworld"

void helloworld::getvalue() {
}
```

The `helloworld` program is defined in `src/Makefile-files` such that the dependency `libhelloworld.la` will be automatically (re)built if necessary. The source file `src/main.cpp` has been adapted for the new header name/location.

```
# -*- makefile-automake -*-

bin_PROGRAMS            += helloworld
helloworld_CPPFLAGS      = -I$(top_srcdir)/include
helloworld_SOURCES       = %reldir%/main.cpp
helloworld_LDADD         = libhelloworld.la
```

```
#include "helloworld/helloworld"

int main() {
  helloworld a;
  a.getvalue();
}
```